# central site collection for provisioned files?

Tags: provisioning, remote-provisioning

There are links to styles etc in master pages and default content delivered by web templates and content provisioning.

Are there clear pros and cons of these files to a central site collection instead of more traditional layouts folder (or ghosted in current webs)?

I am planning to mostly do remote provisioning with default content (images etc) but also adding custom styles (and image links potentially) to the masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

This, by design, is meant to serve multiple purposes, one being the Isolation of resources as Site collections are isolation containers too (navigation, security, etc.). I'm pretty curious how do you plan the architecture of your solution and how is it meant to completely override SharePoint's provisioning process as it seems like you are about to redo it entirely. Most likely you plan to reference your branding artifacts from master pages, styles, etc.

Already the _layouts, _images or _controltemplates folders are shared to the whole farm as virtual folders (mostly authenticated), whereas those in site collection could also be left accessible to anonymous users.

Then you should also consider content publishing scenarios and multi-language scenarios, and even more Themable ones (styles, images), which get compiled as soon as one changes the theme.

Comment: well, some simple provisioning of default content mostly.  in some cases we might also provision master pages etc to publishing pages. Maybe one question would be masterpage referencing a stylesheet from a 'central hub site collection'...